# Gyro-based mechanical stabilization in robotics

Tags: microcontroller, robotics, gyro, mechanical, gyroscope

I'm from a computer engineering background and have a good knowledge about programming microcontrollers. I want to create a small plastic plane that is always kept parallel to ground regardless of the motion I apply to it. I can imagine that I would need a gyroscope to detect the applied movement, but the question is, Is there a programmable device that I can directly use for this? Also do I need motors for that sake? It will be great if you can give me a better design than the one I'm imagining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [MEMS gyroscopes](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00254118.pdf) which have everything packaged into a single chip and provide a digital bus for communication. For most applications these are a suitable substitute to a full-sized mechanical gyroscope, and are really easy to use.

However, because your post says you want a plane the be parallel to the ground, a gyroscope may not be an appropriate tool by itself because it measures orientation relative to a set internal reference point; this will only work if you expect your ground to be flat (or piecewise flat like stairs). It won't work if you want to keep your plane to follow the contour of a hill it is flying over. You will need some other feedback mechanism (likely complex optical sensing such as LIDAR) if you want your plane to follow the contours of the ground.